# Добавление события в календарь программно

Tags: android, события, calendar

Я пишу приложение, менеджер событий.
Есть какие-то события внутри приложения. Должна быть возможность добавить событие в календарь на телефоне **программно**. То есть, меня не интересует специальный intent, который откроет приложение календаря, где я смогу заполнить форму для добавления события (с некоторыми предзаполненными полями). Меня интересует именно тот кейс, когда я нажимаю кнопку в приложении и, никуда из него не уходя, добавить событие в календарь.

У меня уже даже есть код, который отлично справляется с этой задачей на Android 5.0:

```
    val startMillis: Long = 1555406400000
    val endMillis: Long = 1555499400000
    val name = "Event"
    val description = "Awesome event"
    val allDay = false

    val values = ContentValues().apply {
      put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis)
      put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis)
      put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, name)
      put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description)
      put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, allDay)
      put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3) //Don't know why `3`, just copied from some example from inthernet
      put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, ZonedDateTime.now().zone.id)
    }

    val contentUri = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI
    activity.contentResolver.insert(contentUri, values)
```

Но вот на Android 7.0, например, этот код не вставляет в калеендарь ничего. Необходимые разрешения на чтение/запись (WRITE_CALENDAR, READ_CALENDAR") в календарь точно получены на момент выполнения кода. Есть ли какие-то идеи, почему это не работает и как с этим справиться?

Comment: попробуйте так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779758/can-i-add-event-to-calendar-without-letting-user-know-in-android

Comment: @IvanVovk а чем код из принятого ответа в этой ссылке отличается от моего кроме рандомного ID календаря?

Comment: В зависимости от устройства, может быть не тот id календаря. [Здесь можно посмотреть, как найти нужный календарь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215180/what-should-be-calendar-id-while-adding-event-to-calendar-in-android)

Comment: В зависимости от устройства, может быть не тот id календаря. [Здесь можно посмотреть, как найти нужный календарь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215180/what-should-be-calendar-id-while-adding-event-to-calendar-in-android)